# When I buy a domain name, what am I actually getting?

Tags: domains, dns, domain-registration, domain-registrar, ownership

I can buy a domain name from GoDaddy or similar, and then I get to associate it with some IP address I have control over (e.g. a web server).  **But when I buy a domain name, what happens on the registrar's end?**  More specifically, *what aspect of the registrar's infrastructure is updated to reflect my ownership of a domain name I purchase?*

Comment: The WHOIS record?